# Excel IF AND statement with multiple results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to develop the formula based on the IF(AND) statement, which will throw more than 2 results. Usually, it's just 2 (value if true and value if false). I am just wondering if it could be possible to have something like the "nested" output values i.e. Value 1 if True, Value 2 If true within the false, and Value 3 if false within the false.

I have the calendar work and I would like to put the "%" for Saturday's column and "Cost" for Sunday's one.

[image]

but with the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(AG9,2))=7,"Cost",IF(WEEKDAY(AG9,2)=6,"%",AG9))
```

am just able to reproduce the second one.

[image]

Is there any way to have 3 output values or should I develop the same one in the separate row?

Comment: This works for me: `=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(AG9,2),6,"%",7,"Cost",AG9)` Even your formula would work remove the `AND()` function : `=IF(WEEKDAY(AG9,2)=6,"%",IF(WEEKDAY(AG9,2)=7,"Cost",AG9))`

Comment: Ah yes! I've forgotten about the SWITCH function. It works fine. Thank you, Bro.

Comment: Posted as an answer as well! to keep it documented as it is working on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, OP needs to remove the `AND()` function. using `SWITCH()` looks more cleaner and neater here:

[image]

---

```
=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(A1,2),6,"%",7,"Cost",A1)
```

---

Or,

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=7,"Cost",IF(WEEKDAY(A1,2)=6,"%",A1))
```

---

Or,

```
=SWITCH(WEEKDAY(A1:L1,2),6,"%",7,"Cost",A1:L1)
```

---

**Note:** Change cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.